# LINQ with conditional where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have this LINQ:

```
    private static IQueryable<Contract> getValidContracts(DbContext context, DateTime date,int clientId)
    {
        return (from contract in context.Set<Contract>()
                where contract.ValidityDate >= date
                where contract.ClientId == clientId
                select contract);
    }
```

in LINQ I gave this row:

```
 where contract.ClientId == clientId
```

I want this row will be included in where clause only if **clientId** variable not equal to zero.

Any idea how can I lmake it elegant?

Answer (score 7):

Just add a check for 0 in the where

```
where ((contract.ClientId == clientId && clientId != 0) || clientId == 0)
```

Comment: It will not be good if the collection contains data with `clientId` as `0`

Comment: @arash.zh I understood "I want this row will be included in where clause only if clientId variable not equal to zero." to mean "get all of the results if clientId = 0" which I think this statement will do

Comment: why not simply `where (clientId == 0 || contract.ClientId == clientId)` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Since client id is an external variable you can check it outside the LINQ:

```
if(clientId==0)
{
   return (from contract in context.Set<Contract>()
                where contract.ValidityDate >= date
                select contract);
}
else
{
 return (from contract in context.Set<Contract>()
                where contract.ValidityDate >= date
                where contract.ClientId == clientId
                select contract);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For dynamic queries it's better to use the fluent syntax. In this particular case, you can use something like this

```
private static IQueryable<Contract> getValidContracts(DbContext context, DateTime date, int clientId)
{
    var query = context.Set<Contract>().Where(contract => contract.ValidityDate >= date);
    if (clientId != 0)
        query = query.Where(contract => contract.ClientId == clientId);
    return query; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can modify the condition as:

```
where ((clientId!=0)?(contract.ClientId == clientId):true)
```